# Useful Human Vocalizations

Tags: human, sound-design

I've got a bitch of a cold right now, but my voice has this awesome bassy, gravelly quality to it. So I figured I should take advantage of this vocal state and get some potentially useful wild lines, groans, grunts, etc. to add to the library. But without a script or specific project in mind I'm drawing a complete blank.

Suggestions?

Comment: Brilliant list guys! This was just the kind of stuff I needed to kick start the brain. I'll have to set it aside for a week or so while I finish another project, but I'll share the results when it's all edited up! Thanks!

Comment: @Steve I just thought that maybe some deep prolonged growling - has to be prolonged - would be a good element to use in the "100 wooshes in 10 minutes" technique.

Answer (score 4):

Some ideas:

Just do some growls.

Do some growls that create transients (kind of like when you say "aaaaaahhhhh" but in a really slow almost clicking sound).

Then do the gamut of emotions so you have them in case you do some animated movie in the future that you need curious or whimpering or scared emotions for a monster...

Do some laughing too just for the hell of it.

Do some screams and roars like a charging soldier.

"Come here!!"

"Get back here!!"

"I'll kill you!!"

I don't know - think of wild lines for a video game you might do in the future.

Remember to record them at 192K so you can pitch and process at the utmost.

BUT MOST OF ALL!!!!

If you have a phlegmy throat and it affects your breathing, record yourself breathing - some really really good dirty breathing might be a cool texture.

Answer (score 4):

Sing the lowest note you can and hold it for as long as possible. Record at 192k and pitch down for interesting artifacts!

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Utopia's awesome list:

-Cough

-Breathe in with a growl: more like a snarl

-Read random lines from a newspaper/book (helpful when slowed down/speeded up/spliced)

Answer (score 3):

Do some vocals performed to be reversed i.e. make a typical monster growl (whatever that is!) & observe the shape of the sound & how you're making it, then perform it in reverse order.... eg if it 'normally' has a [big attack, big build & then slows to a gutteral growl] perform the reverse ie [start with a slow growl and build to a big roar and then stop suddenly after a loud short snappy outburst]

Also if you want to get rich, do some random Crap FM Radio IDs... 'hi, you're listening to another piece of sh+t mindless FM station regurgitating the same old tunes you heard in your youth and have never grown out of.... CRAP FM, playing all the (S)HITS!" - I'm sure you can sell it to hundreds of commercial FM stations (if only they were honest with themselves)